Python sqlalchemy: Cannot access new created children by parent before commit
I have one to many relationship between two models (Parent and Child)
and I want to access the new created children by parent object before the commit
   class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(TEXT, nullable=False)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id', onupdate='cascade', ondelete='cascade'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", backref="children")

I created new child objects by parent_id (which exists in the session) and add them using bulk_save_objects
    new_children = [
        Child(parent_id=parent_obj.id, name=child_name)
        for child_name in children_names
    ]
    db_session.bulk_save_objects(new_children)

I tried to access the new children by parent, before db_session.commit()
parent_obj.children

the result is empty list since the new children are not associated to the parent
My question is, What is the better way to access new created children from their parent, before commit?

From the bulk_save_objects docs: "This method is a legacy feature as of the 2.0 series of SQLAlchemy. For modern bulk INSERT and UPDATE, see the sections ORM Bulk INSERT Statements and ORM Bulk UPDATE by Primary Key." … and … "The mapped objects are persisted as is, and are not associated with the Session afterwards.

@GordThompson thanks for your answer, but I tried the new methods and the problem does not work

I dunno, new_children = [Child(parent=parent_obj, name=child_name) for child_name in children_names] followed by db_session.add_all(new_children) seems to work for me.
